# xsi:schemaLocation and pom.xml

Tags: xml, maven, xsd, xml-namespaces

I was going thru maven pom.xml which starts with...

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
```

1. Why do I need to use xsi:schemaLocation here? I understand its a way to discover XSD that has a target namespace., but when I use **xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"** I don't need to mention schemaLocation?
2. When I try overriding the prefix xsi with something else (say xsitest) editor shows it invalid. Is it a standard prefix keyword one should use? I thought prefixes can be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask "Why do I need to use xsi:schemaLocation ...?"

Do you?  Whether you need to use `xsi:schemaLocation` or not depends on the validators and other schema-aware processors you are using:  xsi:schemaLocation is one way, but not the only way, to bind namespaces to particular schemas.

You are right to expect that a document should remain valid if you change the prefix to which the XSI namespace is bound.   If your software is showing you an error, then perhaps there is an error in the software, or perhaps you did not rebind the prefix correctly.

Comment: So for xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" I dont use  xsi:schemaLocation, how do I know which validator/schema aware processor is discovering the xsd?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question.  It sounds as if you are asking for help finding out what software you are running, but I'm having trouble imagining how that could be so.  Either you are invoking a schema validator, in which case you should consult its documentation.  Or you're invoking some other software, which is invoking a validator on its own initiative, in which case again I'd look at the documentation.  You do not need to use xsi:schemaLocation to specify a schema location for the XSD namespace, since all conforming XSD processors have knowledge of that namespace built in.

Comment: I was just wondering why we have to specify xsi:schemaLocation in many XSDs in our project making it more verbose. I also dont know how an XML schema validators will bind schema to a namespace.

Comment: Well, either you do have to specify xsi:schemaLocation in a lot of places, or you don't.  If you do, the reason will be that the software you have chosen to use requires it.  If you don't, it will be because the software you have chosen to use can use other methods (configuration files, catalogs, local repositories, you name it) to find schema documents.  Either way, the way to find out what is true is to read the documentation for the software you are using.  In short:  RTFM.